# Ionic 3 cant get the repo Appodeal

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, appodeal

I'm trying to add Appodeal in my app, but when i launch the command :

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-cordova-plugin.git
```

I got this error :

```
Installing "com.appodeal.plugin" for android
Failed to install 'com.appodeal.plugin': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/faycal/Downloads/ionic/topquotes/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

How to fix this ? 
I use IONIC 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try to remove and add your android platform

```
ionic cordova platform rm android --save
ionic cordova platform add android@latest --save
```

2) Try this

```
npm install
```

3) Change the version of node and cordova

Comment: Thank's, i add it with the first solution, when i try to generate APK, i got this error :

A problem occurred evaluating project ':com.appodeal.plugin:adcolony'.
> Could not get unknown property 'cdvCompileSdkVersion' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension